# Is it possible to access a value of a variable in a v-for from outside the v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, v-for

So I have a Vue page where I'm looping through a few items and I have the following code:

```
<div v-if="behavior !== 'selected' && filterItems.length >= 5"></div>
<div v-for="(itemName, index) in filterItems" :key="index">[stuff]</div>
```

Basically I'm looping through some items from an API, but I also want to conditionally show an element if there's 5 or more of those items, otherwise I want it hidden.  That element needs to exist outside the loop, but it needs to check how many items are in the loop.

Interestingly enough, the above code works, but it also throws console errors, presumably because I'm accessing "filterItems" outside of the loop itself.

(here's the console error:  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined")

Any ideas on how I can avoid throwing these errors and accomplish what I need in as vue-native a way as possible?

---

As requested, here's the code declaring `filterItems`.  It's just a prop declared as an array:

```
props: {
    filterItems: Array,
    behavior: String,
  },
```

It's being passed in from a parent component as an array.

---

**UPDATE:  A POSSIBLE SOLUTION?**

So I don't know if this is the best way to do this or not, but I was able to get the desired result by doing the following.  I'd love to hear feedback on if this is a satisfactory solution:

I added a data value:

```
data() {
    return {
      displaySearch: false,
    };
  },
```

Then added:

```
updated() {
    if (this.behavior !== 'selected' && this.filterItems.length >= 5) {
      this.displaySearch = true;
    }
  },
```

Then ran a check against the new boolean:  `v-if="displaySearch"`

My thinking is that the check run against `displaySearch` after the page renders and it avoids the TypeError.  I tried mounting it, intially and it broke immediately.

---

**Final Solution**
See the answer below from Stephen Thomas.  I settled on this as it appears to me to be the simplest and most elegant answer.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to access or where. The error you are getting will be thrown when `filterItems` is undefined, but you are not trying to access that inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> presumably because I'm accessing "filterItems" outside of the loop itself.

Nope. `filterItems` is not defined by the `v-for` loop. It's defined (or it should be defined) in the component's `props` object. As such, it's completely accessible anywhere in your template.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

That indicates that `filterItems` isn't defined. The parent that includes this component isn't providing a value. You can define a default (empty) array for the property:

```
props: {
    filterItems: {
        type: Array,
        default() {
            return [];
        }
    },
    behavior: String
}
```

or you can fix the parent

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I gave this a shot and it works, but now I have a new mystery, which is why the parent is returning undefined values at all.  Thank you for this insight!

Answer (score 2):

I think it starts the filterItems as an empty array already solves, for example:

```
date () {
     return {
         filterItems: []
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue doesn't allow declared properties to be accessed outside v-for (to avoid clashes between properties)

you can declare a global boolean variable to show or hide the component? or inject a property into your objects to hide or show